# What's wrong? I get : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl

I am trying to create the `STS_Acces_Tok` amazon SP-API call to get the `acces_key`, `acces_secret` and Session Token. Do you see any error in the creation of the Signature?

I have this functions:

```
function AMAZON_Get_STS_Acces_Token ($Refresh_token, $IAM_Key, $IAM_Secret_Key, $LWA_Key , $LWA_Secret_Key, $Region, $RoleArn) {

    $amz_date_time = getAmazonDateTime();
    $amz_date = getAmazonDate();
    $service ="sts"; 
    
    $Method = 'GET';
    $CanonicalUri = "/"; 
    $CanonicalQueryString = urlencode("Action"). "=". urlencode("AssumeRole"). "&" .
                urlencode("RoleArn") ."=". urlencode($RoleArn) ."&".
                                urlencode("RoleSessionName")."=".urlencode("STSGS")."&".                                        
                                urlencode("Version"). "=". urlencode("2011-06-15");
                    
    $CanonicalHeaders = array(); 
    $CanonicalHeaders[] = 'host:'.trim($service .".". $Region . ".amazonaws.com");
    $CanonicalHeaders[] = 'x-amz-date:'.trim($amz_date_time);
                        
    $SignedHeaders = "host;x-amz-date;";
    
    $Payload = ""; 
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Obtenemos la firma a enviar en la llamada //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $Firma_AWS = sign_request($Region, 
                                $amz_date_time, 
                                $amz_date, 
                                $RoleArn, 
                                $IAM_Key, 
                                $IAM_Secret_Key, 
                                $service, 
                                $Method, 
                                $CanonicalUri, 
                                $CanonicalQueryString, 
                                $CanonicalHeaders, 
                                $SignedHeaders, 
                                $Payload);
    
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sts.'.$Region. '.amazonaws.com/?'.$CanonicalQueryString,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $Method,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('x-amz-date: '.$amz_date_time,
        'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential='.$IAM_Key.'/'.$amz_date.'/'.$Region.'/sts/aws4_request,
        SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date,
        Signature='.$Firma_AWS),
    ));


    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $Error = curl_error($curl);

    echo "<br><hr>".pre($response).pre($Error);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    return $response;
    
}

function sign_request($region , $amz_date_time , $amz_date, $RoleArn, $IAM_Key, $IAM_Secret_Key, $service, $Method, $CanonicalUri, $CanonicalQueryString, $CanonicalHeaders, $SignedHeaders, $Payload ) {


    $Algoritmo = "sha256";
    
    // Transformamos en cadena + saltos de carro para cada valor, incluso el último
    $CanonicalHeaders = implode("\n", $CanonicalHeaders);
        
    //Step 1: Create a canonical request

    $canonical_request  = $Method."\n";
    $canonical_request .= $CanonicalUri."\n";
    $canonical_request .= $CanonicalQueryString."\n";
    $canonical_request .= $CanonicalHeaders."\n";
    $canonical_request .= $SignedHeaders."\n";
    $canonical_request .= hash_hmac($Algoritmo,$Payload, true);

    $canonical_Screen = str_replace("\n","<br>", $canonical_request); 

    $Hash_Canonical_request = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, $canonical_request, true);
    


        $Canonical_Headers  = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"."\n"; //algorith
    $Canonical_Headers .= $amz_date_time."\n";  //amz_date_time
        $Canonical_Headers .= $amz_date . "/" . $region . "/" . $service . "/" . "aws4_request"."\n"; // credential_scope
    $Canonical_Headers .= $Hash_Canonical_request; // Step 2: Create a hash of the canonical  request
    
    $string_to_sign = $Canonical_Headers;

        
    // Crear la clave de firma

    $kSecret = 'AWS4' . $IAM_Secret_Key; // $kSecret is the AWS secret key from IAM user
    $kDate = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, $amz_date, $kSecret, true);
    $kRegion = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, $region, $kDate, true);
    $kService = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, $service, $kRegion, true);
    $kSigning = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, 'aws4_request', $kService, true); 

    // Calcular la firma de la solicitud
    $Signature = hash_hmac($Algoritmo, $string_to_sign, $kSigning); 
    
    
    return trim($Signature);
}
```

Comment: Why not use the AWS PHP SDK for this? Let someone else do the heavy lifting.